# Database locked SQLite Java

Tags: java

I'm making some programme for checking approaches scales for different usernames. When I call function DodajObrisiPristupe(table, comboBox), it says database locked. I searched for solutions and all says that it's probably that I didn't close connection somewhere, but I can't find where. Can anyone please help me?

```
public void DodajObrisiPristupe(JTable tabela, JComboBox<String> korisnickoime)
{
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tabela.getModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        String serijskibroj = model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        boolean pristup = (Boolean)model.getValueAt(i, 4);

        if(ProveriDaLiPostojiPristup(serijskibroj, korisnickoime.getSelectedItem().toString()) == true)
        {
            if(pristup == false)
                ObrisiPristup(serijskibroj, korisnickoime.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

        else
        {
            if(pristup == true)
                DodajPristup(serijskibroj, korisnickoime.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public boolean ProveriDaLiPostojiPristup(String serijskibroj, String korisnickoime)
{
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + naziv + ".db");

        stmt = c.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRISTUPI;");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            if(Decrypt(rs.getString("korisnickoime")).equals(korisnickoime) && Decrypt(rs.getString("vage")).equals(serijskibroj))
                return true;
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {

        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

```
public void DodajPristup(String serijskibroj, String korisnickoime)
{
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + naziv + ".db");

        stmt = c.createStatement();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO PRISTUPI (KORISNICKOIME,VAGE) " +
                  "VALUES ('" + Encrypt(korisnickoime) + "', '" + Encrypt(serijskibroj) + "');"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {

        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
public void ObrisiPristup(String serijskibroj, String korisnickoime)
{
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + naziv + ".db");

        stmt = c.createStatement();

        String sql = "DELETE from PRISTUPI where KORISNICKOIME = '" + Encrypt(korisnickoime) + "' AND VAGE = '" + Encrypt(serijskibroj) + "';";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {

        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is easier for us to debug if your method names are english

Comment: I'll fix that next time, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing your connection in `ProveriDaLiPostojiPristup(String, String)`.

You should always wrap your connections in try-with-resources or try-finaly, so they are always closed.

> ```
>    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + naziv + ".db");
>
>     stmt = c.createStatement();
>
>     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRISTUPI;");
>
>     while(rs.next())
>     {
>         if(Decrypt(rs.getString("korisnickoime")).equals(korisnickoime) &&
>             Decrypt(rs.getString("vage")).equals(serijskibroj))
>             return true;
>     }
>
>     rs.close();
>     stmt.close();
>     c.close();
> ```

What happens, is that your method returns true, but because the execution is stopped there, it won't execute the lines below it. This can be countered if you wrap the statements in a [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block:

```
try(c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + naziv + ".db")){

   try(stmt = c.createStatement()){

     try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRISTUPI;")){

        while(rs.next())
        {
            if(Decrypt(rs.getString("korisnickoime")).equals(korisnickoime) && Decrypt(rs.getString("vage")).equals(serijskibroj))
                return true;
        }

     }
   }
}
```